# Sweet alert malfunctions in combination with Selenium's browser.click()

Tags: selenium

I have a swal:

```
swal({
            title: 'Success',
            text: 'Something',
            type: 'success',
            closeOnConfirm: true
          },function(){
            $("#somethingModal").modal("hide");
            $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop : 0
            }, 1500);
          });
```

HTML for button of interest is `<button class=confirm>`.

Now, if I use Selenium's `browser.click('.confirm')` the swal does close but the follow-up code i.e. hiding the modal and the animation are not triggered. Is there any way around this? Is there maybe another Action I can use that properly triggers the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the `div` with classes `sweet-alert` and `visible` and then perform any actions on the alert.

See the answer from  Sundling on 17 Dec 2015 at [GitHub](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/485) sweet alert performs a 500ms fadeIn when opening the modal.

During this-

> time the OK/Cancel buttons will not run the callback function, it will
>   close the modal instead. An unexpected/confusing behavior according
>   to me.
>
> sweet alert will add the class visible when the animation has finished.
>
> Using Capybara for testing you could use the following:
>
> `within ".sweet-alert.visible" do
>   ... 
>   end`

Comment: Could you add more information to your answer, so that if the github account is ever disabled, the critical information remains here.

Comment: Made some changes as requested by @KatePaulk